# AutoCAD show whole command run through dialog box

Tags: dialog, command, lisp, autocad

In Autocad, some commands (like HATCH) will call a dialog box to pass parameter value to command, I just want to know how to get rid of prompt dialog box and execute the command only in command line? In other words: How do I know the template to complete a command?

Answer (score 0):

Run command starting with `-`. Like this:

```
(commnad "-_HATCH" ......... )
```